# Convert INT to TIME and get next hour or half hour value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am converting INT to time using below query.

```
DECLARE @TimeVal INT
SET @TimeVal = 115024
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, (@TimeVal / 10000) % 100, 
       DATEADD(MINUTE, (@TimeVal / 100) % 100, 
       DATEADD(SECOND, (@TimeVal % 100), CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME(0)))))
```

it will give the result `11:50:24`. and then i need need to round of this time value to nearest hour or half hour value. The expected out put for this time input is `12:00:00`.

Sample Input and Output

```
11:15:12 -> 11:30:00
10:56:58 -> 11:00:00
22:01:59 -> 22:30:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

```
DECLARE @TimeVal INT
SET @TimeVal = 111512
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,case when (((@TimeVal / 100) % 100)>30 and ((@TimeVal / 10000) % 100)<24) then ((@TimeVal / 10000) % 100)+1 else (@TimeVal / 10000) % 100 end, 
DATEADD(MINUTE,case when ((@TimeVal / 100) % 100)>30 then 0 when ((@TimeVal / 100) % 100)<30 then 30 end,
 DATEADD(SECOND, 0, CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME(0)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code is not working for 113012. It is returning NULL. Have added <= 30 in MINUTE CASE statement to handle the mentioned input.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the number to a time using seconds only:

```
   convert(time, dateadd(second, (@timeval / 10000) * 60 * 60  +  ((@timeval / 100) % 100) * 60 + @timeval % 100, 0))
```

Then, there are multiple ways to do the rounding.  I think `case` is simplest:

```
(case when @timeval % 100 >= 30
      then convert(time, dateadd(second, (@timeval / 10000) * 60 * 60 + ((@timeval / 100) % 100) * 60 + 60, 0))
      then convert(time, dateadd(second, (@timeval / 10000) * 60 * 60 + ((@timeval / 100) % 100) * 60, 0))
 end)
```